# Firebase CLI – failed to get status of function deployments

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I've been struggling with this problem for several days. Basically, `firebase deploy` started to throw an error at the end. The noteworthy part is that everything seems to work fine, but it's just annoying to get that error at the end.
I've completely no idea what might cause this. It just started to be like that, out of nowhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Logs (look at the end):

```
$ firebase deploy                                                                                               out 130 20:18:32

=== Deploying to 'project'...

i  deploying storage, firestore, functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build /Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/project/functions
> npm run lint && tsc


> functions@ lint /Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/project/functions
> eslint --ext js,ts src

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  firebase.storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
✔  firebase.storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: reading indexes from firestore.indexes.json...
i  cloud.firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
✔  cloud.firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  storage: latest version of storage.rules already up to date, skipping upload...
✔  firestore: deployed indexes in firestore.indexes.json successfully
i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (238.28 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
✔  storage: released rules storage.rules to firebase.storage
✔  firestore: released rules firestore.rules to cloud.firestore
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function api(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function UpdateAir(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function DeletePhotosFromComment(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function DeletePhotosOnDelete(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function CompressPhotos(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function CreateUser(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function DeleteUser(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function Backup(us-central1)...
i  scheduler: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  pubsub: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: scheduler job firebase-schedule-UpdateAir-us-central1 is up to date, no changes required
i  functions: scheduler job firebase-schedule-Backup-us-central1 is up to date, no changes required
⚠  functions: failed to get status of all the deployments
You can check on their status at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project/functions/logs

Error: Failed to get status of functions deployments.

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

Comment: If you're getting an error from the CLI that's not helpful or actionable, contact Firebase support for help with diagnosis. The will probably want to see a detailed debug log from the CLI using the --debug flag.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support